# Nested Template arguments when I know the typenames already

Tags: c++, templates

in this case where I have an `Algorithm` class:

```
template <typename SourceType, typename DestType>
class Algorithm {
  bool apply() { ... return true;}
};
```

I am trying to create a `Helper` that abstracts the user from fully defining the `Algorithm` class. This is my idea of an implementation:

```
template <typename DataType, template <typename, typename> class AlgorithmType>
bool Helper(const DataType* soure, DataType* dest) {
  AlgorithmType<DataType, DataType> alg;
  return alg.apply();
}
```

Is the `Helper` function correct? Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem correct. But your `apply` doesn't return anything, which is UB.

As for improvements, you could reverse the order of template arguments and let `DataType` be deduced:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class AlgorithmType, typename DataType>
bool Helper(const DataType* soure, DataType* dest) {
  AlgorithmType<DataType, DataType> alg;
  return alg.apply();
}
```

Now you can call it with

```
Helper<Algorithm>(const_ptr, ptr);
```

You can block deduction on the second argument to make it more robust:

```
template<typename T> struct identity{ using type = T; };
template<typename T>
using block_deduction = typename identity<T>::type;

template <template <typename, typename> class AlgorithmType, typename DataType>
bool Helper(const DataType* soure, block_deduction<DataType*> dest) {
  AlgorithmType<DataType, DataType> alg;
  return alg.apply();
}
```

and now you can call it with

```
Helper<Algorithm>(const_ptr, const_ptr);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Helper` function is correct, but you may want to put `typename DataType` as the last template parameter so that it can be deduced from the function call:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class AlgorithmType, typename DataType>
bool Helper(const DataType* soure, DataType* dest) {
  AlgorithmType<DataType, DataType> alg;
  return alg.apply();
}
```

Now you can use `Helper` as follows:

```
int main()
{
    const int* some_src_ptr = /*...*/;
    int* some_dst_ptr = /*...*/;
    Helper<SomeAlgorithmTemplate>(some_src_ptr, some_dst_ptr);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can pass the whole algorithm as a template parameter, and let the user deal with choosing `SourceType` and `DestType`:

```
template <typename SourceType, typename DestType>
class Algorithm {
public:
  using source_type = SourceType;
  using dest_type = DestType;
private:
  bool apply() {}
};

template <typename Algo>
bool Helper(const typename Algo::source_type* soure, typename Algo::dest_type* dest) {
  Algo alg;
  return alg.apply();
}
```

Now you can use `Helper` as follows:

```
int main()
{
    const int* some_src_ptr = /*...*/;
    int* some_dst_ptr = /*...*/;
    Helper<SomeAlgorithmTemplate<int, int>>(some_src_ptr, some_dst_ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider making an algorithm independent on compile time parameters and use e.g. something like this:

```
struct Algorithm {
   template <class Source, class Dest>
   bool operator()(Source source, Dest dest) {
       //...
       return something;
   }
};
```

and then:

```
template <class AlgType, typename DataType>
bool Helper(const DataType* soure, DataType* dest) {
  AlgType alg;
  return alg(source, dest);
}
```

To run:

```
Helper<Algorithm>(source_ptr, dest_ptr);
```